# How to read csv field with comma and split string in the field to a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to read csv and split some output string with delimiter into a list, but when I tried to read the list using array, it threw error saying "list index out of range". The list should have 2 elements. Please, see attached codes. Please, kindly help me pointing out what was wrong with the code. The index 0 works just fine.

The csv file look like this:
ID, Full Name, Last First Name

1, John Smith, "Smith, Jonh"

2, Camil Johnson, "Johnson, Camil"

3, Bang Dong, "Dong, Bang"

4, Charles Simpson, "Simpson, Charles"

```
import csv
with open('testfile.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        # print(row)
        # print (row[2])
        a = row[2].split(sep=", ")
        print(a[1])
```

[image: Sample csv file]

Comment: What output are you currently getting vs expected output?

Comment: Are you setting `newline` to a zero-length string?

Comment: I expected a as a tuple, since it returned [lastname, fistname], when I print(a). However only a[0] is available which is the lastname. When I tried to print(a[1], it threw error saying index out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas the same way I coded with csv works very well. Thanks Nathaniel.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')
a = df['Last First Name'].tolist()
for row in a:
    b = row.split(', ')
    print(b[1])
```

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')
```

This will read in your csv file into a data frame, and you can access the columns and convert them to lists like this:

```
df['Full Name'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your are using "," as a delimiter, but your "Last First Name" Column also contains commas.

In this line of code:

```
a = row[2].split(sep=", ")
```

you are trying to separate the first name from the last name and assume it returns a tuple which you are trying to display here:
    print(a[1])

**The Problem** is a will not be a tuple, because of the comma thats inside of this column. Instead there will be a row[3], in your case "Smith" will be in row[2] and "John" in row[3]. **To avoid this, use a different delimiter**.

Comment: I tried print(row[2]) it returned 'lastname, firstname' which is correct. What I am trying to do is to split row[2] into tuple or list. When I print(row[2].split(sep=', ') it returned [lastname, firstname] which is as expected either. Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are expecting. How should the output of a[2] look like?
What you have to do for sure is skipping the header line by using "next(reader, None)" directly after you created your reader